# useEffect dependency only if a certain variable is present then only watch it as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following set of running code:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (field[1].isActive === true) {
  handleMore();
 }
}, [field[1].text]);
```

The issue is sometimes `Field` doesn't come in the json-response, so then this code shows an error.
As I cannot put useEffect inside some conditional statement (as per React Guidelines, all useEffects should always run in same order), is there any way I may add some code in dependency such as `[field.length? field[1].text: null]`. I am not sure.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use optional chaining or && for this.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (field?[1]?.isActive === true) {
  handleMore();
 }
}, [field?.[1]?.text]);
```

Or

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (field?[1]?.isActive === true) {
      handleMore();
   }
 }, [field && field[1] && field[0].text]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward solution (since there is no context to this question) might be using optional chaining.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (field?.[1]?.isActive === true) {
  handleMore();
 }
}, [field?.[1]?.text]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

like:

```
useEffect(() => {

 ...

}, [field?.[[1]]?.text]);
```