# Is it a good practice to use optional chaining inside reacts useMemo/useEffect dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-usememo, optional-chaining

I'm working on a large react app where performance matters.
At first I avoided using objects properties inside useMemo dependencies (I was avoiding dot notation inside dependencies). But I have seen this in react's documentation so I think it is safe.
Now my linter sometimes complains when I don't include optional chaining inside the dependencies, and I end up doing this:

```
  const artworks = useMemo(() => {
    let list = availableArtworks.artworks;
    if (route.params?.artworkId) {
      // Some Stuff here
    }
    return list;
  }, [availableArtworks, route.params?.artworkId]);
```

It looked dirty to me at first but now I'm considering starting to use it. If `route` has no `params` property, then the whole `route.params?.artworkId` expression should be falsy, right? Then if the object changes, and we suddenly have a `params` and `artworkId` the useMemo should reexecute and take that value into account?

**So my question is:** Is it safe to use it like so or is it dirty in any ways ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect dependency only if a certain variable is present then only watch it as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603018/useeffect-dependency-only-if-a-certain-variable-is-present-then-only-watch-it-as)

Answer (score 2):

### Syntax wise

Looks safe. The one line I worry about is:

```
let list = availableArtworks.artworks;
```

If the key "artworks" isn't a primitive, you might modify it without intending to.

Also, your dependencies array should look like:

```
[availableArtworks?.artworks, route.params?.artworkId]);
```

### Do you really need useMemo?

Lastly, if performance is super important, I would definitely reconsider (and measure) if you do need the `useMemo`. `useMemo` is for heavy computational lifting. Do you have some recursion happening? Some intensive calculation? Factorials? Long Loops? If the answer is no, bringing `useMemo` will in fact decrease performance.

Recommend you to read this [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) from Kent C. Dodds (Author of react-testing-library and remix) about performance.